# How to replace periods with X?

Tags: javascript

```js
var mystring = "this.is.a.test";
mystring = mystring.replace(/./g, "X");
console.log(mystring);
```

I expect the output of `thisXisXaXtest` but my log show `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` is special character in regex ( which means match anything except new line ) you need to escape it

```js
var mystring = "this.is.a.test";
mystring = mystring.replace(/\./g, "X");
console.log(mystring);
```

[`DOT`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Answer (score 1):

`.` matches every character other than newlines. To use it how you are intending, it needs to be escaped: `\.`.